# VBScript - Not able to get regex to match in script, even if regex validates in online tester

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm testing the following .vbs snippet om my Windows 10 laptop and it won't match. The regex itself if just fine according to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/9KJRtM/1) - it does match on the month, but when running the script it does not match - and since my knowledge of VBScript is pretty low - I cannot seem to solve the puzzle. I assume that there is something specific for VBScript and Regex that I'm missing.

```
Dim dateAndTime  
dateAndTime = Mid("Tue, 8 Oct 2019 11:47:37 +0200 (GMT+02:00)", 6, 20)
Wscript.Echo "dateAndTime=" & dateAndTime

Set objRegExp = new RegExp
objRegExp.Global = True

' Neither patterns works, but all is fine in regex101
objRegExp.Pattern = "^\w{3,},\s\d{1,2}\s(\w{3,})"
'objRegExp.Pattern = "^\w+,\s\d+\s(\w+)"
'objRegExp.Pattern = "\w+, \d+ (\w+)"

If (objRegExp.Test(dateAndTime) = True) Then
    ' never gets here
    Wscript.Echo "Match"
else 
    ' always ends here
    Wscript.Echo "No match"
end if
```

And in case someone wonders - We are using hmailserver as email server for our test environments - and I'm trying to mass delete messages. Problem is that the messages has English locale but the server has Norwegian locale. So for instance October is 'Oktober' and 'Okt' in short in the Norwegian locale. So I need to update the script and replace 'Oct' with 'Okt' to be able to create a date object and then see if the message is older than X days in order to delete it.

Comment: After Replace you want to get something like this `Tue, 8  okt 2019 11:47:37 +0200 (GMT+02:00)`  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your aim is to get something like `Tue, 8  Okt 2019 11:47:37 +0200 (GMT+02:00)` Instead of `Tue, 8  Oct 2019 11:47:37 +0200 (GMT+02:00)`

---

So you can modify your script like this :

```
Dim dateAndTime  
dateAndTime = "Tue, 8 Oct 2019 11:47:37 +0200 (GMT+02:00)"
Set objRegExp = new RegExp
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "(^\w{3,},\s\d{1,2}\s)(\w{3,})"
If (objRegExp.Test(dateAndTime) = True) Then
    Wscript.Echo "Match"
    strReplace = "$1 Okt"
    NewDateTime = objRegExp.Replace(dateAndTime,strReplace)
    wscript.echo NewDateTime
else 
    Wscript.Echo "No match"
end if
```

Comment: Actually - the code snippet does not solve my issue entirely, but it made me understand what the root cause was. And that was not the regex, but the use of the mid()-function. When doing the regex on the returned value from mid() it fails, so I need to update the whole string before using the mid-function in order to use cdate